# Old "org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException ... could not initialize proxy - no Session": don't understand why

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

I'm getting a LazyInitializationException and am not sure why. I'm storing an entity (BaseEntity with id) as data on a primefaces tree node in order to make it dynamic (i.e. onNodeExpand event handler that fetches expanded node children from db). I'm aware that the entity becomes detached after the render which is why I do the following in the onNodeExpand to add the child nodes:

```
    Product parentProduct = productService.findById(entity.getId());
```

This is returning an entity which I presumed would be "attached", but when I iterate over a lazy loaded OneToMany relationship I get the LazyInitializationException:

```
    for (Module module: parentProduct.getModules()) {
```

What I am not understanding here?

**Edit:**

ProductService is a @Stateless EJB injected as follows into a ViewScoped Bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MasterBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3153934047649103375L;

    TreeNode root;

    @EJB
    ProductRepo productService;
```

findById is in a generic CrudRepository:

```
    public E findById(final K id) {
            return em.find(entityClass, id);
    }
```

Comment: This is related to the way you handle your transaction. Show us the code that loads the `parentProduct` and uses its modules and we will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Hi Ean: Edited and added more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem with a system that I was developing. To fix this issue what you have to do is get the object that contains the collection and then access the collection within the same session like the following:

```
@Transactional
public User retrieveUser(String username)
{
    User user = hibernateUserDao.getUserByUsername(username) 
    /*whatever your method of getting something from the database */

    Collection collection = user.getCollection();
    /*Then you can access and manipulate the collection object*/
}
```

This is caused because if you retrieve the user object, the collection by default isn't retrieved for performance reasons, but if you do it all in one transaction, the database connection still exists so hibernate will go and retrieve the instance of your collection.

Another pitfall is trying to retrieve the user in one transaction then starting a new one to access your collection object. Hibernate doesn't let you do this, it throws a similar error.

Tell me if that doesn't make sense.

TL;DR: You have to retrieve your parent object then access your collection object within the same transactional session.

Comment: Hi James: this was indeed the solution although it took a bit of further research to find out what I was misunderstanding. My error was that I thought that because both methods were REQUIRES_NEW, that the new transaction being created for the first method was being propagated to the second method. This is not the case. From the Enterprise JavaBeans book: "The new transaction’s scope covers only the Required EJB and all other EJBs accessed by it. Once the method invoked on the Required EJB is done, the new transaction’s scope ends."

Comment: ahh yes. With all the Spring @Transactional annotations, I wouldn't even bother defining REQUIRES_NEW or any other isolation level. Hibernate is clever enough to work that out by itself. At least it has been in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a OneToMany relationship between Product and Modules without a FetchType explicitly defined, then the fetch type [by default is Lazy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching).  If that's the case, then you need to make sure you're iterating over the lazily loaded collection within a Hibernate session.

There's a lot at play with Hibernate sessions that could define the lines of demarcation for a Hibernate session, especially when you're using a library/framework.  I'm not familiar with primefaces, but if you [read up on Hibernate sessions here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html), you may be able to then see how Hibernate sessions work with with it.